# Changing the cssclass for a <tr> using vb.net

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net-2010

I have this  and I want to hide rows dynamically using vb.net codebehind.
I am using VS2010.

This is my table:

```
<table>
    <tr id="FromDateRow">
        <td><asp:Label ID="FromDateLabel" runat="server">From date:</asp:Label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtFromDateF" class="needs-datepicker" />
            <asp:TextBox id="txtFromDate" CssClass="hidden" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="ToDateRow">
        <td><asp:Label ID="ToDateLabel" runat="server">To date:</asp:Label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtToDateF" class="needs-datepicker" />
            <asp:TextBox id="txtToDate" CssClass="hidden" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="CustomerCodeLabel" runat="server">Customer Code</asp:Label>:</td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="CustomerCodeDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="CINumberLabel" runat="server">CI Number</asp:Label>:</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="CINumberTextBox" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
Select Case value
            Case DisplayDates.FromDate
                ToDateRow.CssClass = "hidden"
                FromDateRow.CssClass = ""
            Case DisplayDates.ToAndFromDate
                ToDateRow.CssClass = ""
                FromDateRow.CssClass = ""
            Case Else
                ToDateRow.CssClass = "hidden"
                FromDateRow.CssClass = "hidden"
        End Select
```

For some reason I cannot access the ToDateRow and the FromDateRow from my codebehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it.
By adding the runat="server" i was able to access the row.
And then I found the "visible"-property.
Now it works just fine.
Thx for the help

Answer (score 1):

You must have

`runat="server`

tag in table and tr to access  from code behind.

After comment :

```
ToDateRow.Attributes("class") = "CssClass";
```

Comment: I noticed that as well. So I've corrected that in the meantime.
But I still do not have something like CssClass for the row

Answer (score 1):

The objects you are trying to reference in codebehind (the relevant tr elements) needs to be defined as runat="server"

If CssClass is not a known property for the object instance try using the following:

```
rowObject.Attributes.Add("class", "hidden");
```